# How to run a simple 'Hello World' app on shared hosting with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have been running through some basic tutorials with node.js locally on my desktop and all works fine.

I have been trying to run one of the simple 'Hello World!' apps on my 'live' hosting environment.  This is not an active website, just some basic web hosting I use for trying things out. My hosting provider offers a node.js addon for a small amount extra per month which I recently signed up for.

I have amended the code in my file (named app.js) so that it references the host and port provided to me by my hosting provider rather than use localhost as it has been previously. The code looks like:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '195.62.28.216';
const port = xxxx;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

With xxxx being substituted for the port allocated to me.

If I kick this off using my SSH client (PuTTY) by running node app.js, I get the message:

```
Server running at http://195.62.28.216:xxxx/
```

However, if I visit that URL, I just get a timeout error:

**This site can’t be reached
195.62.28.216 took too long to respond.**

When I connect to the host using PuTTY, using the username and password my hosting provider gave to me, it appears to default to a folder named /home/my_username. This is the location of my 'Hello World' app file.

I have contacted my hosting provider's support area, but thought I would post here too whilst awaiting a response in case anybody can point me in the right direction of what I may be doing wrong.

Many Thanks, any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you run command node app.js after access your server?

Comment: Take it you're connecting to the correct port and not just the ip?

Comment: are you connecting to http://195.62.28.216:xxxx or just http://195.62.28.216?

Comment: Yes to all of the above, but I think I solved the issue, see below. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all above for the quick responses.  I think that the problem is that I was going trying to access the 195.62.28.216:xxxx URL directly from my browser but I think it's set up so that this can only be accessed from my actual web hosting environment.

In other words, I added the below to my .htaccess file on my cloud hosting account:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://195.62.28.216:xxxx/ [P,L]
```

And when I now go to my website, I get 'Hello World!' as expected. Now I just need to figure out how to make it so that this only happens when I access a specific folder on my website and not the whole thing... :-)